# .hide() Method not acting on variables

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, variables, hide

I'm trying to hide an element on click using the .hide() method. In the code below, I can hide object1 when I select it specifically by ID. I have the element stored in a variable but when I use hide() on the variable, it doesn't work. Why would the method not work when I use the variable, but work just fine when I select it specifically?

Here is the code:

```html
<div id="object1">Object 1</div>
<div id="object2">Object 2</div>
<input type="button" id="button" />

<script>
  $(document).ready(() => {

      const object1 = $('#object1');
      const object2 = $('#object2');
      const button = $('button');
  });

  button.addEventListener("click", () => {
      $('#object1').hide();
  });

</script>
```

When I use the following code (replacing $('#object1') with its variable) the code doesn't execute.

```js
  $(document).ready(() => {

      const object1 = $('#object1');
      const object2 = $('#object2');
      const button = $('button');
  });

  button.addEventListener("click", () => {
      object1.hide();
  });
```

Am I doing something wrong, or is there limitations in JS surrounding this?

EDIT:

Even after moving the event listener into the document ready, the code still isn't executing. Here is the most recent code

```html
<div id="object1">Object 1</div>
<div id="object2">Object 2</div>
<input type="button" id="button" />


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>


<script>
    $(document).ready(() => {
        const object1 = $('#object1');
        const object2 = $('#object2');
        const button = $('#button');

        button.addEventListener("click", () => {
            object1.hide();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: object1 is not inside $(document).ready .. just move it before you close the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a closure problem. The scope of your click function does not know about object1.
You have two options:

**Option 1:** Move your event listener inside the document ready. I would go for this option personally since it avoids polutting the window object

```js
  $(document).ready(() => {
    const object1 = $('#object1');
    const object2 = $('#object2');
    const button = $('button');

    button.addEventListener("click", () => {
      object1.hide();
    });
  });
```

**Option 2:** Move your vars outside so all methods have them available.

```js
  let object1 = null;
  let object2 = null;
  $(document).ready(() => {
    object1 = $('#object1');
    object2 = $('#object2');
    const button = $('button');
  });

  button.addEventListener("click", () => {
    object1.hide();
  });
```